# How to get the element on which taphold is fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, touch, preventdefault

Can you please help me to locate on which element "taphold" is fired by using JS, jQuery, or jQuery Mobile?

My HTML structure is like the below

```js
<script>
    $(document).on("pagecreate", function () {      
        $("#myFilesListView").bind('contextmenu', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myFilesListView").bind("taphold", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(false);
            event.stopPropagation();           
            var ID = $(this).child().attr("id");
            alert(ID);
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="header"></div>
        <div data-role="main">
            <ul data-role="listview" id="mylistview">
                <li class="mydata" id="1"> some conetent</li>
                <li class="mydata" id="2"> some conetent</li>
                <li class="mydata" id="3"> some conetent</li>
                <li class="mydata" id="4"> some conetent</li>
                <li class="mydata" id="5"> some conetent</li>
              <!--ids are not in predefined sequences and there may be 100s of list--> 
            </ul>
        </div>
 <div data-role="fotter"></div>
</div>
```

In my JavaScript code I am able to prevent the default behavior of taphold, but I am not getting how to get the Id of a particular list as soon as a user tap and hold on that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the taphold to the li elements instead of the listview:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {      
    $("#mylistview").on('contextmenu', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });

    $("#mylistview li").on("taphold", function (event) {
        var ID = $(this).prop("id");
        alert(ID);
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6m2u7a4s/)**

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply.....its working like a charm, i did it like this         "   $(document).on("taphold", ".touchableImage", function (event) {
      var ID = $(this).attr("id");
      hm.files.rightClickOptions(ID);
    }); "

Comment: I have a new doubt regarding contextmenu, and I need help for that, so should I post that here or create a new question

Comment: @ManjeetSingh, posting as new question will get more people looking at it and likely a quicker answer...